# Stand alone Java application with Cognito Federated Identities and Microsoft AD

Tags: swing, oauth-2.0, amazon-cognito, federated-identity

I wanted to extend an existing stand alone Java tool (developed on Swing) to be integrated with Cognito Federated Identities to access the tool with my Windows AD credentials and also have roles and groups defined in Cognito to restrict access to the backend API's which the tool can access.

Currently the only way I find is to Open a Browser Window from my code and redirect to the Authorization URL, have a http listener running on my standalone application which can receive the callback through which I can get the authorization code.

Is this the only way to fetch the authorization code for this use case or are there any better approach for the same?

Note: Microsoft User Agent does not work for my use case